# MVC: Datatable does not contain any data after publishing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, model-view-controller, datatables

I start by saying this is the first project I have ever published and apologize in advance if I give you too much or too little information.
So, I published this MVC project to a business server.  It works but the data in the datatable is not showing. Although, when I just debug in Visual Studio there is data.
This project has 2 tabs:
The first tab is to show the datatable in question which uses [u]Entity Framework[/u];
The second tab also has a datatable(a yadcf) which shows data that is accessed via [u]Ado.Net[/u].
Data in the first tab does not show, while it does in the second tab.

The datatable on the first tab references to this link:

While for the second tab I imported the yadcf datatable. Below is how I reference to it:

Also, when I do F12 under the "Elements" I can see the references to the datatables(see attached photo).  Plus it looks like the datatable and its functionalities(search box, paging, column names) show up but without any data in it.

[image: Datatable without data]

IN CASE YOU WANT TO SEE IT, THIS IS THE CODE OF THE INDEX PAGE WHICH INCLUDES THE DATATABLE:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#firstTab">View All</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#secondTab">Add New</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#thirdTab">Knowledge</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#fourthTab">IT Tasks</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="firstTab" class="tab-pane fade in active">@Html.Action("ViewAll")</div>
    <div id="secondTab" class="tab-pane fade in">@Html.Action("AddOrEdit")</div>
    <div id="thirdTab" class="tab-pane fade in">@Html.Action("ViewAllKnowledge")</div>
    <div id="fourthTab" class="tab-pane fade in">@Html.Action("ViewAllTasks")</div>
</div>



@*jQuery Datatable CSS*@
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">                                
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css">                    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/colreorder/1.5.2/css/colReorder.dataTables.min.css">                    


@section scripts
{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

    @*jQuery Datatable JS*@
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>                         
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/colreorder/1.5.2/js/dataTables.colReorder.min.js"></script>                        

    <script>
        function activatejQueryTable() {

            var table = $('#ticketTable').DataTable({
                rowReorder: { selector: 'tr' }, 
                colReorder: true,              
                "stateSave": true,              
                "stateDuration": 0,             
                "autoWidth": false,             
                "columnDefs": [
                    { "width": "40px", "targets": 0, "visible": true },     
                    { "width": "150px", "targets": 1, "visible": true },    //dtLastUpdated
                    { "width": "250px", "targets": 2, "visible": true },    //vcSubject
                    { "width": "150px", "targets": 3, "visible": true },    //vcFrom
                    { "width": "53px", "targets": 4, "visible": true },     //vcPriority
                    { "width": "90px", "targets": 5, "visible": true },     //vcAssignedTo
                    { "width": "53px", "targets": 6, "visible": true },     //vcStatus
                    { "width": "90px", "targets": 7, "visible": true },     //vcRequestType
                    { "width": "90px", "targets": 8, "visible": true },     //vcLocation
                    { "width": "90px", "targets": 9, "visible": true },     //vcCategory
                    { "width": "90px", "targets": 10, "visible": true },    //dtAnticipatedCompletion
                    { "width": "100px", "targets": 11, "visible": true }     //edit and delete buttons
                ],

                //Create the dropdowns
                responsive: true,
                "bAutoWidth": false,            
                initComplete: function () {

                    this.api().columns([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]).every(function () {      
                        var column = this;

                        var select = $('<select class="myDropdown"><option value=""></option></select>')

                            .appendTo($("#filters").find("th").eq(column.index()))
                            .on('change', function () {
                                var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(this).val());
                                column.search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false).draw();
                            })
                            .on('click', function (e) {
                                e.stopPropagation();                                
                            });

                        column.data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j) {
                            $(select).append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
                        });
                    });
                }
                //End of create dropdowns
            });

        }
        //});

        $(function () {
            activatejQueryTable();
        });

</script>
}
```

FYI, when I published I used the below:

UNDER CONNECTION:
Publish method: Web Deploy
Server:  (Business Server Name)
Site name:  HelpDeskSupport
Username:  myUsername
Password:  myPassoword

UNDER SETTINGS:
Under "DBModel" as the datasource I added the SQL Server name with its username and password.
I checked the "Use this connection string at runtime..."

Could you please help me figure out what I have done wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked the console on the version which 'doesn't work'?

Comment: What are the HTTP responses in your network tab?

Comment: There is nothing in the network tab...

Comment: The console tab does not have anything in it either, no errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.  There was some permission code that I set up which was not allowing to display records.  It makes sense as the datatable seemed to show up so I was thinking that it was some Entity Framework issue.